# Which version of PHP-FPM is necessary to work with WP 3.5?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to establish a blog with NGINX and PHP-FPM.

I wonder if my version of PHP should work with WordPress

```
/usr/bin/php-cgi -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: magickwand: Unable to initialize module
PHP 5.2.17 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Sep 17 2012 00:15:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator`
```

Comment: Have WP blog turned on. So it works with my actual version of PHP-fpm  reported 0.6 by phpinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official system requirements](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/), PHP version 5.2.4 or greater should work. However, some plugins and / or themes may require PHP version 5.3, though. BTW, PHP 5.2 has reached its [End of Life](http://php.net/eol.php) a couple of year back (in 2011).

Comment: to be more clear on question: i have php 5.24 and it works perfectly with WP 3.5 but i changed for nginx and added a PHP-fpm.rpm to maintain server request. Then my question is about this mentioned PHP-fpm.

Comment: Php-fpm is process manager available as part of php. So, when it comes to versions, PHP = php-fpm.

Comment: No, as phpinfo(); in section cgi-fcgi tell me that i have php-fpm active and php-fpm version 0.6. If i look at the top of phpinfo page there is info about php version that is 5.2....

Comment: In fact i just started the WP3.5 on  my nginx+fpm by fixin rightway rewriterules for site.conf. so the question still for amazing part

Comment: According to [the official php-fpm page](http://php-fpm.org/download/), php-fpm 0.6.x is the latest version. So, that should work just fine with WP.

Comment: I'm going to mark Q as solved: nginx >=0.91 and php-fpm >=0.6 work fine with WP 3.5. Just do attention to location and rewrite rules in nginx config files.